# How to cbind two series of array in to one dataframe by for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I have two series of array, pan1,pqn2,,,pn30 and read1,read2,,,read30, I want to cbind them into one dataframe with colnames like pan1,read1,pan2,read2,,,pan30,read30 by a for loop in R, how should I do? Here's my try but doesn't work

```
pan <- objects(pattern='^pan[0-9]+$')
read <- objects(pattern = '^read[0-9]+$')
for (i in 1:30) {
       for (j in 1:30) {
            if (i==j) {
                  panread <- cbind(pan[i],read[j]) 
        }
       }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one solution in base R:

generate vector of `objects`' names observing the pattern pan1, read1, ..., pan30, read30

```
objects_to_bundle <- as.vector(matrix(c(objects(pattern = '^pan*'),
                                        objects(pattern = '^read*')
                                        ),,2, byrow = TRUE
                               )
                     )
```

get a list of the objects by `lapply` as follows:
`get` objects by object name, convert this into a named `structure` (list) and return this list `as.data.frame` (which is a rectangular list of columns anyway):

```
as.data.frame(structure(.Data = lapply(objects_to_bundle,
                                       function(n) as.vector(get(n))
                                       ),
                        .Names = objects_to_bundle
                        )
              )
```